# QbyteArray data split

Tags: c++, qt, split, qlist, qbytearray

I have an array with size of n. I want to split this array with size of y. It need to be x times newarray with size of y. I need multidimensional array like `myarray[x][y]`. Output need to be `myarray[0][0...y],myarray[1][0...y],....myarray[x][0...y]`. How can I do it in qt(by using `QList<QByteArray> myarray`) or other solutions?
For example

```
    for (int i = 0; i < y; i++)
    {
        myarray[i] = array[i];
    }
```

Comment: Are you aware of how to convert a plain 1D array to a 2D array?

Comment: No, how can do that in qt? Can I create an array as myarray[x][y] in qt?

Comment: What I meant was, if you knew how to convert a plain 1D array to a 2D array, would you be able to apply it to a QList array?

Answer (score 1):

> How can I do it in qt(by using QList myarray)

Reusing your names (*myarray* for a QList is not very intuitive)

```
#include <QList>
#include <QByteArray>
#include <iostream>

void split(const QByteArray & a, 
           QList<QByteArray> & l,
           int n)
{  
  for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i += n)
    l.push_back(a.mid(i, n));
}

int main()
{
  QByteArray array("azertyuiop");
  QList<QByteArray> myarray;

  split(array, myarray, 3);

  for (QList<QByteArray>::const_iterator itl = myarray.constBegin();
       itl != myarray.constEnd();
       ++itl) {
    const QByteArray & a = *itl;

    for (QByteArray::const_iterator ita = a.constBegin();
       ita != a.constEnd();
       ++ita) {
      std::cout << *ita << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Execution result :

```
a z e 
r t y 
u i o 
p
```